# SQL select the latest record on joined tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to retrieve the property which an user paid a tax last.

have two tables `person_properties` and `property_taxes`

```
person_properties
---------
person_id
property_id
```

```
property_taxes
---------
property_id
year
```

What I tried so far:

```
SELECT pp.person_id, MAX(pt.year) 
FROM property_taxes pt
JOIN person_properties pp ON pt.property_id = pp.property_id
GROUP BY pp.person_id
```

This gives me the `person_id` along the max year.
But I actually need the `property_id`, the property which an user paid last.

If I replace `pp.person_id` by `pp.property_id`, I then get all properties, of course.. not grouped by person, which excludes an user that has more than one property.

Any little tweak that can help me get the desired result?

Comment: is there only 'year' as time column?
If it is, how do you plan finding latest one? there must be multiple property in the same year

Comment: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) for some reference

Comment: @berkancetin nice question, its an anual tax, and there is a constraint in the DB so it wont happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DISTINCT ON` might do what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pp.person_id)
       *
       FROM property_taxes pt
            INNER JOIN person_properties pp
                       ON pp.property_id = pt.property_id
       ORDER BY pp.person_id ASC,
                pt.year DESC;
```

Comment: @queroga_vqz . . . This does not just "work as well".  This is the best way to solve this  problem in Postgres and it should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
SELECT
    pt.property_id,
    pt.year
FROM
    property_taxes pt,
    person_properties pp,
    (
        SELECT
            pp.person_id p,
            MAX(pt.year) y,
        FROM
            property_taxes pt
        JOIN person_properties pp ON pt.property_id = pp.property_id
        GROUP BY pp.person_id
    ) sub
WHERE
    pt.property_id=pp.property_id AND
    pp.person_id=sub.p AND
    pt.year=sub.y
```